# Use daterange table to also return empty resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of messsages per user, per day for the following table:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| msg_id  | user_id | m_date     |
+-------------------+------------+
|   1     | 1       | 2011-01-21 |
|   2     | 1       | 2011-01-23 |
|   3     | 1       | 2011-01-23 |
|   5     | 2       | 2011-01-23 |
|   6     | 2       | 2011-01-24 |
|   8     | 1       | 2011-01-23 |
|   9     | 2       | 2011-01-23 |
|  10     | 1       | 2011-01-24 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

The desired outpur would be:

```
1 2011-01-21 1
2 2011-01-21 0
1 2011-01-22 0
2 2011-01-22 0
1 2011-01-23 3
2 2011-01-23 2
1 2011-01-24 1
2 2011-01-24 1
```

I use the following query:

```
SELECT m_date, COUNT(msg_id ) AS volume
FROM messages
GROUP BY user_id, m_date
ORDER BY user_id, m_date ASC
```

But here, days with a volume of zero are being left out of the resultset:

```
1 2011-01-21 1
1 2011-01-23 3
2 2011-01-23 2
1 2011-01-24 1
2 2011-01-24 1
```

I want those days in the resultset, however. So I understood I should make use of a "daterange" table, which contains all the dates for which I want a result:

```
+---------+------------+
| date_id | d_date     |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 2011-01-21 |
| 2       | 2011-01-22 |
| 3       | 2011-01-23 |
| 4       | 2011-01-24 |
+---------+------------+
```

However, I don't know how to use this table in accordance with the first one to get the resultset I need. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be accomplished using cross join:

```
SELECT user_id, d_date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN messages.m_date = d.d_date then 1 end) Volume
FROM messages
CROSS JOIN datetable d
GROUP BY messages.user_id, d.d_date
ORDER BY messages.user_id, d.d_date ASC
```

[Sql Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23eae/8).